# How can I pass in a $1 into a trap and signal

Tags: bash, parameters, signals, bash-trap

```
sigusr1() { echo $1;}
trap sigusr1  SIGUSR1
```

I'm a bash newbie!

I have the above trap and signal code in my .bash_profile.To trigger `sigusr1`, i simply call `Kill -SIGUSR1 pid` in the terminal. I googled to find out how I can pass in a parameter into `sigusr1` but I can't find anything except for if i use it as trap 'sigusr1 hello' SIGUSR1

But that defeat the purpose. I would like to pass in the parameter via the terminal. How can I pass in a parameter via the kill command so that `sigusr1` function can echo it out?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this. Why do you want to? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @etanReisner oops, sorry i miss your comment. I use this technique to create this rubygem https://rubygems.org/gems/aka2. It reloads dotfile after I edit it programatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To pass a parameter to function called by `trap`, change your trap call to:

```
trap 'sigusr1 $(cat ~/sigusr1-args)' SIGUSR1
```

Send the signal like this:

```
echo arg1 > ~/sigusr1-args;kill -SIGUSR1 PID
```